# How can I count the length of char in a char array without using any loop?

Tags: arrays, char, sizeof, string-length

so i was practicing my c language and there i come to a need that how can i count the length of character in a character array because when i use sizeof() in that i got the whole length of array..although i can use "for loop" but i can't use that in that question so is there any other way to do this..

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<math.h>

int main()
{
    int i,N;
    char a[20];
    printf("enter the string");
    scanf("%s",a);
    puts(a);
    N = sizeof(a); 
    printf("%d",N);
    return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT:-

```
enter the string                                                                                     
helloguys                                                                                            
helloguys                                                                                            
20
```

Comment: strlen() uses loop internally. It cannot be the answer. Have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved in 2 ways:

**1) Using `strlen()` function defined in `string.h`:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<math.h>

int main()
{
    int i,N;
    char a[20];
    printf("enter the string");
    scanf("%s",a);
    puts(a);
    N = strlen(a); 
    printf("%d",N);
    return 0;
}
```

Be aware that, `strlen()` uses loop internally. According to the definition of `strlen()` in `string.h` library, the possible implementation as per [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strlen) is:

```
std::size_t strlen(const char* start) {
    const char* end = start;
    while(*end++ != 0);
    return end - start - 1;
}
```

**Therefore the second way without using using loops directly or indirectly can be recursion.**

**2) Using recursion:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<math.h>

int LengthofString(char *string) 
{  
    if (*string == '\0')  
        return 0; 
    else
        return 1 + LengthofString(string + 1); 
}

int main()
{
    int i,N;
    char a[20];
    printf("enter the string");
    scanf("%s",a);
    puts(a);
    N = LengthofString(a);
    printf("%d",N);
    return 0;
}
```

**PS:** Beware about the predefined library functions and their internal implementations before using them.

Answer (score 0):

`strlen()` function will help you to solve your problem.Don't forget to add `#include<string.h>` before using `strlen()` function.

Comment: strlen is a loop that is hidden behind a c library function

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit late to the party, but you could calculate the length of a string (or any memory) by dividing the memory by the size of the packed values:

```
char_array / sizeof(char) = number of chars
```

if it results in 12 f.e., you have your length of 12. Don't forget a string is closed with a trailing null-byte, so TECHNICALLY your string is

```
(array / byte ) -1  // a char is a single byte == 8
```

The strlen function in deepak's answere will assemble to an internal loop, and recursion is technically not a loop but will assemble to something similar with call operations and a counter variable.